# How to add a phantom character to the beginning of a verbatim block

Tags: spacing, verbatim, fancyvrb

I am trying to understand the `commandchars` of fancyverb's `Verbatim`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\phantom{foo}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\!\!]
\phantom{bar}
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]] {
  type ID <: Ident[S#Tx]
  type Tx
}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

This print `bar}` in the first line of the verbatim. I have three questions:

1. Why is this printed at all if I use `\phantom`.
2. why is the closing curly brace included?
3. I cannot use `commandchars=\\\{\}` because it conflicts with the curly braces of the programming language printed. So I use `[commandchars=\\\!\!]`. However when I try to insert `\phantom!bar!` I just get the error `\FancyVerbGetLine has an extra }`.

Actually all I want to achieve is to print a leading empty line which doesn't work—instead a half-height line appears. So my thought was the easiest would be to enforce the height of the first line by adding a phantom character.

Comment: You shouldn't use the same character both for opening and closing braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in

```
commandchars=\\\!\!
```

You have to specify three *distinct* characters in the form `\<char>`; the first will be used in place of the backslash, the second in place of the opening brace and the third in place of the closing brace. Thus something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\!\?]
\phantom!bar?XYZ
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]] {
  type ID <: Ident[S#Tx]
  type Tx
}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

I added `XYZ` just to show that the phantom is honored. One in a line by itself is useless: just leave a blank line.

[image]

Let's see what happens in your example. The backslash is defined to work also in `Verbatim` blocks to escape commands. The `!` is first made equivalent to `{` for opening groups, then it is immediately made equivalent to `}` for closing groups. So you won't be able to pass multitoken arguments to macro, because you don't have a left argument delimiter.

When `\phantom{bar}` is processed, `\phantom` is executed normally (the backslash has been given its normal meaning) and it finds a token `{` not preceded by a left argument delimiter. Remember that we are in verbatim mode! So `{` is taken as the argument of `\phantom` and it results in a space equivalent to a letter. Then `bar}` is printed verbatim.

Your attempt with

```
\phantom!bar!
```

doesn't work, because it would be equivalent, outside `Verbatim`, to `\phantom}bar}` which is illegal. With

```
commandchars=\\\!\?
```

and

```
\phantom!bar?
```

we're doing what in normal contexts would be `\phantom{bar}`.

Comment: Thanks! Why doesn't verbatim throw an error when the chars are not distinct? Anyway: "One in a line by itself is useless: just leave a blank line." Precisely not! If I add the single blank character I get the follow spacing in the first line, if I just leave a blank line without the phantom character, the line only has half height (in my scenario, in a minipage in a sub figure).

Comment: Why isn't an error thrown? Because the developer of `fancyvrb` didn't deem it necessary.

Answer (score -1):

I got an understanding that there is a problem with many latex commands such as `\phantom` not being compatible with the idea of the group block of commandchars. A workaround here is to define a parameterless helper commmand, like so:

```
\newcommand{\worstLanguageEver}{\phantom{I}}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\$\$]
\worstLanguageEver
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]] {
  type ID <: Ident[S#Tx]
  type Tx
}
```

Comment: the problematic part are the `{..}` in your code which should be printed verbatim. They are also seen as argument of a function. The resaon why the linebreaks are gone.